# Candlestick Plot from a Pandas DataFrame retry

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, finance

I am new to matplotlib and need some guidance.  I have being trying to reproduce this code from "Candlestick Plot from a Pandas DataFrame" as a way to learn  by adding a "read_csv" function.

my error message keep saying "valueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 5 elements"

my questions is:

1. what am I missing in the code?  I read in the cvs, I use the right columns of data, and I understand there is a reset of index, but I don't know why it keeps getting an error.

please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt


df = pd.read_csv("/Users/paul/Documents/python     (original)/Quant/sp500.csv", usecols=['Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close'])


#Reset the index to remove Date column from index
df_ohlc = df.reset_index()


#Naming columns
df_ohlc.columns = ["Date","Open","High",'Low',"Close"]

#Converting dates column to float values
df_ohlc['Date'] = df_ohlc['Date'].map(mdates.date2num)

#Making plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=1)

#Converts raw mdate numbers to dates
ax1.xaxis_date()
plt.xlabel("Date")
print(df_ohlc)

#Making candlestick plot
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,df_ohlc.values,width=1, colorup='g',       colordown='k',alpha=0.75)
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: In which line of the script do you get the error? Please provide the full error traceback. There is no information about the input file present. (See [mcve]) So you may not get an answer here, because nobody can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I apologize for lack of info.  the read in of the first few records are                                                                                                                   Date         Open         High          Low        Close
0  2015-09-22  1961.390015  1961.390015  1929.219971  1942.739990
1  2015-09-23  1943.239990  1949.520020  1932.569946  1938.760010
2  2015-09-24  1934.810059  1937.170044  1908.920044  1932.239990

Comment: the full error message is "the full error message is "raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paul/Documents/python (original)/Quant/candle stick chart from stackoverflow v4.py", line 17, in <module>
    df_ohlc.columns = ["Date","Open","High",'Low',"Close"]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3094,

Comment: in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/properties.pyx", line 65, in pandas._libs.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas/_libs/lib.c:45255)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 473, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2836, in set_axis
    (old_len, new_len))

Comment: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 5 elements"  thank you.

Comment: Please provide this as [edit] to the question, not in the comments (how should anyone be able to read this?). It's not entirely clear how many columns the file you read in has. However the error suggests that there is one column too much after the reset_index.

Comment: thanks for point that out for me.  I am still quite new at using stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need "0", "1", "2" before each line in your .csv file. You must first remove that and then:

- If you're going to reset the index, you need an actual index column in your dataframe, so add `index_col` like this:
  `df = pd.read_csv("/Users/paul/Documents/python     (original)/Quant/sp500.csv", usecols=['Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close'], index_col= 'Date')`
- Convert your date column from string to datetime : 
  `df_ohlc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ohlc['Date'])`

EDIT:
If you can't  delete the 0, 1, 2... column in your csv file because it's too large, modify the first row to make the 'index' column appear like this:
 
`'index', 'Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close'`

Then, in your code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/paul/Documents/python     (original)/Quant/sp500.csv", usecols=['index', 'Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close'], index_col="Date")
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I appreciate the pointers from both.  I was thinking a way to match the columns.  I was rereading all the functions and tried this  last night with df = pd.read_csv("/Users/paul/Documents/python (original)/Quant/sp500.csv", index_col='Date', parse_dates=True, usecols=['Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close']).  it worked.